# OpenCV and iOS - Getting started

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, image-processing

I am new to iOS development and apologies for a basic question. I am trying to convert an image to grayscaled and threshold it using openCV in iOS. So far, I have imported and setup the framework on xcode. What I am trying to do now is to implement the following features:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Ko3K_xdhJ1I

at 0:24 and 0:53

I tried to follow the tutorial which points to the above youtube video :

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html

and wasn't sure where to paste the above code and in which file?

Many thanks.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Why you are going after Open CV approach, there are loads of methods to convert the image into grayscale.

Comment: Hi, Could you kindly point me in the right direction please.

Comment: are you only trying to change your image in grayscale?

Comment: Yep. Then I want to threshold it by using a slider.

Comment: @Hasnain - If that's all you need, you can do that with a GPUImageThresholdFilter in just a few lines of code: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage and it will even operate on live video. See the FilterShowcase example for how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are helper methods and best written in a separate file. Quite simply,

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/631-how-to-get-c-and-objective-c-to-play-nicely-in-xcode/

1. Put all that image manipulation code in say ImageManipulationHelper.mm and create a header file for the same
2. Create a nice little category for UIImage.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html
which can call these methods in turn to create any image manipulation you might want.

Easy does it. And yeah, read up a bit more on using C++ in objectiveC, if you get into trouble and also about categories. They are some of the niftier features of objectivec

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to add a new file and called it imagetoMat and I get a compilation error:
http://s12.postimg.org/3m1n17d5p/Screen_Shot_2013_06_03_at_12_40_57.png
Sorry for asking basic questions. Really appreciate your help. THanks.

Comment: Sorry mate. I think you might be missing the import directives or something. I cant see the exact error in your picture. Just the place where there are errors. I think it would serve in the long run to pick up the language and a bit of stuff around it. It would save a lot of your time and not to mention the frustration of trying a zillion things that dont work right.

Comment: I apologise. I tried to add the import directive as follows : http://s17.postimg.org/jsvppt2rj/error.png  It should show you the errors as well. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: dont let it rankle mate.. i meant it as an easier way to get things done, nothing else. Anyways, u are in luck. There is someone who has played around with OpenCV in iOS. https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone/tree/master/OpenCVClient I think this should help u out.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were very very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same,using the help of this awesome link

Let me know if you need any further help.

Cheers!!

Edit :

Check this out [ImageFiltering](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters)

Comment: Thanks for that mate. I had tried that initially and got the following error:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums//viewtopic.php?f=20&t=5189#p41972